# AngularJS add row in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, forms

I use angularJS and I have one table on my page, I made one button to add row with input fields. My solution work good for adding rows and value of input fields in form, but doesn't work well where I need to delete particular row. I use one function for form, and another for adding and deleting rows.

It's like this:

```
<div ng-init="tmplCtr.newPeople()">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <input name="postsubmit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit" value="Save table" ng-click="tmplCtr.newTable(tmplCtr.table)" />
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tmplCtr.editRow()">Add row</button>
</div>

<form name="peopleForm" novalidate>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="place-name">Name</th>
                    <th class="place-value">Lastname</th>
                    <th class="place-options">Options</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="people in tmplCtr.peoples">
                    <td class="place-name"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" ng-model="tmplCtr.peoples.values[$index].name"></td>
                    <td class="place-last"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" ng-model="tmplCtr.peoples.values[$index].lastname"></td>
                    <td class="place-options"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-md btn-delete" ng-click="tmplCtr.editRow($index)">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</form>
```

When I press button add row I get row, but when I press delete row I delete row from screen but last row in array, not by index. Beside that also value of that row is not deleted from form scope. Function is:

```
    function editRow(item) {
        if(item == undefined) {
            vm.peoples.push({});
        } else {
            vm.peoples.splice(item,1);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should not be using ng-model="tmplCtr.table.values[$index].name" instead used ng-model="place.name" and similarly to other fields

On delete button click, you can send the place object.

ng-click="tmplCtr.editRow(place)"

Inside editRow you can look for the place in the array and remove it

Comment: But adding it's ok, I need to delete object from tmplCtr.peoples.values array. I send good index in function edit row, but vm.peoples.splice(item,1); somehow doesn't make a good job

Comment: Couldyou make a plunker ?

Comment: I can't now, when I make I will update here

Comment: You actually iterate in `tmplCtr.peoples` but you apply the `$index` in `tmplCtr.peoples.values` ? Can't say how does this make sense for you.

Comment: Because I have another objects in tmplCtr.peoples, and I want to add another one tmplCtr.peoples.values where I will put all rows I make

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to make two functions, the first one is for adding items, and the second one is for deleting like below:

```
function addEmptyItem(){
   vm.peoples.push({});
}

function deleteItem(index){
   vm.peoples.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Then in your view you can change `tmplCtr.editRow($index)` --> `tmplCtr.deleteItem($index)`

Furthermore it is strongly advised to use this syntax `person.name` etc in your repeat directive.

EDIT:

This is not tested by the way...

Comment: it doesn't work, vm.peoples.splice(index); delete all, if I write vm.peoples.splice(index,1); then delete last row in array

Comment: @Sasa try the updated answer. If it does not work you have to update the `$scope` object. Bet let me know if any issue and I will explain you

Comment: I will, I will look to update question and to make plunker to be easier

Comment: @Sasa You can have a look to this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/7wlffOG2eLXkoqtTgAXQ?p=preview If you have another situation let me know...